# Power adapter sparks and then stop working

Tags: charger

I have an Asus X550C laptop, and I have troubles with his power adapter. The power adapter is 19V, 3.42 A, 65 W. Every time when I plug in power adapter in outlet, there is a little spark but it works fine. Sometimes, that spark is huge, and my power adapter stops charging. I found one way to fix this issue, temporary, like that: I opened the plastic case, and I took that electrical circuit in my hands,  I dropped it on the floor (by mistake) , then I assembled my power adapter, plugged it into outlet (I have wondered if it works) and surprise, it works until that huge spark comes out again, and I need to drop it on the floor to make it work. I know this is not a good ideea, but I need laptop  because I need to work with it. Untill my new charger arrives (2-3 days) I am using this "dropping technique" to make it work.

And my question is, why my power adapter stops charging everytime when that huge spark comes out? May be an issue with the capacitor? Or there is not good connection between the wires?

Comment: Huge spark comes out of where? Out of the plastic case? Out of the wall socket? It sounds as though there is a dry joint somewhere and dropping it is causing it to make contact again.

Comment: Huge spark comes out of the wall socket, sorry, I forgot to specify this.

Comment: Perhaps you have a faulty wall socket. Does the socket give problems when other things are plugged in? Like an electric heater?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I used all my wall sockets with laptop power adapter, and in every single one, I have same problem. If I plug in other electronics, they work fine and that spark is low or doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe there is a dry joint inside of power adapter, just like @Transistor said. But why it stops working only when that huge spark appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the discussion in the comments:

- The flash comes out of the socket during insertion.
- The socket works for other appliances.

The most likely explanation is that there is a dry or broken joint between the plug pins and the circuit board. The pins are going to take the most mechanical abuse. The spark may be escaping through the gaps in the case around the pins.

[image]

*Figure 1. Check the PCB for dry or broken joints. Note the discontinuity in the solder bead compared with the adjacent pins. Source [Pink Fish Media](http://www.pinkfishmedia.net/forum/showthread.php?t=155757).*

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I will check the PCB and if this is the problem, I can fix it by myself :)